# How Insert data to two tables at once?

Tags: sql, reactjs

I want to insert data to two tables at once using form in sql.

table 1

```
expenseID| description | generatedBy | notifyWho | frequencyGeneration
```

table 2

```
divExpenseID | divNo | expenseID | description | date | amount | status
```

expenseID is the primary key of table 1.So it is the foreign key for table 2. When i insert data using a form, i want to fill both tables at once.

Comment: How you insert data normaly? What ORM you use?(if you use)

Comment: You need to run two INSERT statements, one for each table.

Comment: "Insert data to two tables at once" usually means both inserts in one transaction. (So you don't mistakenly insert into one table and not the other.) What DBMS are you using? How do you create the `expenseID`? Is it some auto ID that gets set automatically when inserting a row in the first table?

Comment: What is your backend DBMS (i.e. Postgres, MySql)?  In Postgres you can do a chained `INSERT` and use the values from the first `INSERT` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into the first table table_1 and make sure the expenseID is an identity insert.

```
INSERT INTO table 1( description,generatedBy,notifyWho , frequencyGeneration)  
VALUES('Description sample','Geberated sample','Nofify_name','fq_gebe')
```

Then insert into the second column with the identity insert of the first table as expenseID.

```
INSERT INTO table_1(divExpenseID,divNo , expenseID , description , date , amount , status)  
VALUES (11,5,@@identity,'description','date samoke',125,done)
```

Please ignore the dummy value and use the actual once.